# Format datetime in a specific format

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I am using a WPF TextBlock to Bind a Modified Datetime field and is showing the data , 
But i want to display it in a custom format like this  "DD.MM.YY  HH:MM" .
I tried the below xaml but its not rendering the data in the requested format  but it shows data as mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss long datetime string

```
<TextBlock  Text="{Binding Modified, StringFormat={}{0:DD.MM.YY  HH:MM}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DateLabelStyle}" ></TextBlock>
```

How can i make it to show data in DD.MM.YY  HH:MM format ? Do i need to write separate converters for doing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `DD` and `YY` formats for a [custom date and time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And `MM` for months, `mm` for minutes.

I think you just need

```
<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Modified, StringFormat = dd.MM.yy HH:mm}"/>
```

Comment: i think OP's syntax for string format is correct, but like you mentioned, he has used the wrong format string. However, I don't think your syntax is correct.

Comment: @Mez Updated in the same time when you write a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Modified, StringFormat=dd.MM.yy HH:mm}"/>
```

For more information about standard date and time formats see : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx.

This can also be useful for custom date and time formats : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx.

Comment: ... but probably `dd.MM.yy HH:mm`

Comment: These are not standard date and time formats, they are custom date and time formats.

Comment: No difference its making i tried   <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Modified, StringFormat=dd.MM.yy HH:mm}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DateLabelStyle}" ></TextBlock>

Comment: What is the text block showing, when you use dd.MM.yy HH:mm?